# no error is returning from error function in sqlite transAction

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

I'm using the code below to interact with sqlite Database.

```
var defferd = $q.defer();

         var db = openConn('test1','1.0.0' , 'test1' , 200000);
         db.transaction(insertUserInformation, errorDB, successDB);

         function insertUserInformation(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERINFO (ID UNIQUE, USERNAME , FULLNAME , PROFILEPIC , ACCESS_TOKEN)');
         }

    function openConn(databaseName, dbVersion, dbShowName, dbSize){
        return window.openDatabase(databaseName, dbVersion, dbShowName, dbSize);
     }

    function errorDB(tx, err) {
        defferd.reject(err);
    }

    function successDB() {
        defferd.resolve(result)
    }

return defferd.promise;
```

after running this codeit's OK. but when I change query to insert , errorDB function gets triggered but no error returns and I can't figure out what is that's error.

how can I handle to errors of sqlite transactions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to specify the primary key, so update creating table query to

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERINFO (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, USERNAME , FULLNAME , PROFILEPIC , ACCESS_TOKEN)');
```

note :do not forgot to drop old table before.

after what

```
function insertUserInformation(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('insert into USERINFO VALUES (null, "2", "3", "4", "5");');
}
```

works well for me.

And one more thing:
errol callback (errorDB function) should have only 1 argument

```
function errorDB(err) {
        defferd.reject(err);
        console.log(err);
    }
```

so in this case err will be SQLError object like this:

```
{
    code: 6
    message: "could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (19 UNIQUE constraint failed: USERINFO.ID)"
}
```